# table creation went wrong

Tags: jsp, servlets, el

pardon me for my bad english.

im new to jsp/servlet calling. recently i created a table in jsp to display the output of my request from servlet. the servlet pass the list to the jsp contains 3 fields: date, revcode and amount for 1 month adn it is group by date.

below is the display that i want to do:

```
date       | revcode | revcode | revcode and so on | total
2013-02-02 | amount  | amount  | amount and so on  | sum of the amount for that day
```

and here is my code :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <th> Date </th>
                        <c:forEach var="revcodes" items="${revcodeList}">
                        <th>${revcodes.revcode}</th>
                        </c:forEach>
                        <!--<th> Total </th>-->
                        </thead>

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <c:forEach var="revcodeAmount" items="${revcodeList}">
                                <td>${revcodeAmount.amount}</td>
                            </c:forEach>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

i dont know how to create a table to be like i wanted above. can you guys point me in the right direction. or i need to use other opensource api for tabular record like jasper reports to do this?

here is my screenshot link : http://postimg.org/image/62ajljtcn/

Comment: Are you getting any error message when trying to run that code?

Comment: @CodeMed, so far nope. but it doesnt display as i wanted it to be.

Comment: You can post a print screen anonymously by uploading it to http://postimage.org/ and putting the url in an `img` tag in your posting.  That can help people see what you don't like.

Comment: here is the link : http://postimg.org/image/62ajljtcn/

Comment: it does not show the date, and your table is too wide.  but what else is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

I think it could work:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
    <th> Date </th>
    <th> Total </th>
</thead>
<c:forEach var="revcodes" items="${revcodeList}">
    <tr>
       <td>${revcodes.revcode}</td>
       <td>${revcodeAmount.amount}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

You could also use [DisplayTag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/) this lib help you displaying tabular data also with aggregates and have options to export data.

Comment: will display each line revcode, i post something about what i wanted in my post earlier